# Usage of "to take a chance(on something)"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, definition, idioms-in-context

The definition of ***to take a chance(on something)***  according OALD:-

"to decide to do something, knowing that it might be the wrong choice"

Example given-

**We took a chance on the weather and planned to have the party outside.**

I am having difficulties understanding the sentence, as the definition given seems less useful to me. How I can use the definition in understanding the sentence ?I also want to know about the difference between "to take a chance(The guide book didn't mention the hotel, but we decided to take a chance.) vs to take a chance on something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decided to {plan to hold the party outside} knowing that it might be the wrong choice (because of the weather).

The only difference between "take a chance" and "take a chance on {something}" is that the second one makes it clear what the risk is.  If you say "The guide book didn't mention the hotel, but we took a chance" it is implied (but not explicit) that the risk is that the hotel will not exist, or be shut, or be unclean, etc, depending on context.  It would be possible to say "We decided to take a chance and hold the party outside." and leave it implicit that the risk is the weather.